# react fetch send a pending response

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I am writing my react as a function component. I want to execute fetch and wait for it finished before rendering. but fetch always sends a pending promise and records is null when it renders. How do I make it a synchronous process?

```
export default function SimpleTable() {
const classes = useStyles();


let records = null;
fetch(socket+'get_all_records')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {records = json.record});


return (
        <Paper className={classes.root}>
            <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">DoorId</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Time</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Permission</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Image</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    {records.map(record => (
                        <TableRow key={record.UserID}>
                            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">{record.UserID}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">{record.DoorID}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">{record.Time}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">{record.AccessGranted}</TableCell>
                            {/*<TableCell align="right">{record.ImageID}</TableCell>*/}
                            <TableCell>
                                <img src={socket+'get_image?image_id='+record.ImageID} height="42" width="42"/>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    ))}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </Paper>
    );
```

}

Comment: You can't make `fetch` synchronous. You could have an `isPending` state in your component (show loading spinner), and when fetch finishes, update your state with the data / switch off isPending.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `records` needs to be a state, otherwise reassigning it (`then(json => {records = json.record})`) won't trigger a re-render.

And you can use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) to decide what your component renders depending on the value of `records`:

```
export default function SimpleTable() {
  const [records,setRecords] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(socket+'get_all_records')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {setRecords(response)});
  }, []);

  return (
     !response ? <Loading /> : (
       <Paper className={classes.root}>...</Paper>
     )
  )
}
```